# Convert Base64 to Blob in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, base64, blob

I'm trying to send `base64` image data to Amazon S3.  To do this I convert the `base64` string to a blob using this function.

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    console.log("made it past atob");
    var z = [new Uint8Array(array)];//phonegap stops here  :(
    console.log("made it past Uint8Array")
    return new Blob(z, {type: 'image/png'});
}
```

It works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

However, in phonegap on `Android 4.3` it seams to fail at `[new Uint8Array(array)];`
The reason I think that is Weinre reports "made it past atob" but not "made it past Uint8Array".

Does anyone have a way to convert `base64` to a blob that works in phonegap?

Or maybe a function that doesn't depend on `Uint8Array`?

Comment: This will be a webview version specific issue, not actually a phonegap issue. From doing a search on `Uint8Array android 4.3` I found that it may be a formatting issue. have you tried `var z = new Uint8Array(array);` (remove the braces)?